# Send image from ASP.NET Web API to Angular client

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-core, webapi

I just finished my photos upload functionality.
I'm **storing images in folder** after upload and **I'm storing path to them** in my database.

I want to display this photos in my Angular client and I don't know how can I do this. I can't just send a path to images because I want to display this photos in different components. Is there any solution that gives me possibility to **send images from .NET backend to Angular client**, and how to **display** this images on my web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a path to your image, you can just simply get this path from your database and encode your image to Base64 like this:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dbObject.Path);
string image = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

and send this string to your Angular client.

If you already get response in your client, you can just simply display image from Base64 with something like this:

```
<img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+response.image">
```